# Subcaption: having two subfigures captions on the same line

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

In my document, the `TikZ` pictures have different bounding boxes so the two `subfigures` have staggered `captions`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includestandalone{one}
\caption[short]{long}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includestandalone{two}
\caption[short]{long}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Since you wont have my two standalones, I will show what is happening:

[image]

I would like for the `subcaptions` to start on the same row.

Comment: This should be supported out-of-the-box by [`supcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). See, for example, the visual on p 6 of the [`subcaption` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) when using `\subcaptionbox`. If you replace your `\includestandalone` by something like `\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-a}` and `\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-b}`, do you still have mis-alignment vertically?

Comment: Another solution to this question, using a table, can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276288/problem-while-using-caption-for-rows-of-multiple-figures-in-2-columns-and-many-r.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the desired alignment using the `\subcaptionbox` command instead of the `subfigure` environment; the following example shows a comparison between `subfigure` with default vertical alignment, `subfigure` with bottom vertical alignment, and `\subcaptionbox` (the `H` option from `float` was only used for the example; I am *not* recommending using this placement specidier):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}% just for the example

\begin{document}

Using \texttt{subfigure} with default vertical alignment (undesired result):
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[short]{The left subfigure with a long caption spanning several lines and some more text}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
\caption[short]{The right subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

Using \texttt{subfigure} with bottom alignment  (undesired result):
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[short]{The left subfigure with a long caption spanning several lines and some more text}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
\caption[short]{The right subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

Using \texttt{subcaptionbox}  (desired result):
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{The left subfigure with a long caption spanning several lines and some more text}%
  [.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{The right subfigure}
  [.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, how would I expand this to have as many boxes I want in one line?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati Use 3 or subcaptionboxes of course. Don't forget to set the correct width to the subfigures.

Comment: Is it possible to have captions of two side-by-side figures to have captions that **start** on the same row? eg.: Fig. 1: caption1    ......  Fig. 2: caption 2