# Align captions for unequal sized figures with subcaption package

Tags: subcaption

I have two figures of unequal size (figure 1 is wider and shorter), and I would like to centre-align the two subfigures vertically, but keep the subcaptions aligned at the top (please see attached image). Can this be done with the subcaption package, without modifying the figures themselves?
[image] (figure updated)

```
%preamble
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, aboveskip=-3pt]{subcaption}
%document
       %version1----
            \begin{figure}
            \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, position = top}
            \captionsetup{font={onehalfspacing},skip=-10pt}
            \subcaptionbox{}[0.5\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}}
            \subcaptionbox{}[0.5\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}}

        \end{figure}
        \clearpage
       %version2----
        \begin{figure}[hb]
            \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
            \captionsetup{font={onehalfspacing},skip=-10pt}
                \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.49\textwidth}
                    \caption{}                
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
                \end{subfigure}
                \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.49\textwidth}
                    \caption{}                
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2.pdf}
                \end{subfigure}
```

Comment: Does the following answer your question? [Subcaption: Vertical alignment of two images of different vertical size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239176/134144)

Comment: Hi, I think that solution still centres the subcaption along with the subfigure, whereas I would like the subcaption to be at the top and the figure centred. I can already centre the figure with the [c] option for {subfigure}. I have updated the attached image to better reflect my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like this solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, aboveskip=-3pt]{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\valign{\hsize=0.49\hsize \linewidth=\hsize #\cr
  \caption{}
  \vfill
  \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=\hsize]{example-image}
  \vfill
  \cr\noalign{\hfill}
  \caption{}
  \vfill
  \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
  \vfill
  \cr
}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this works! I am guessing `\newsavebox{\subA} \newsavebox{\subB}` in the preamble can be safely removed.

Comment: @srao Yes, they are a relic from a previous attempt.