# Subcaption: Vertical image alignment - Pass through image height

Tags: vertical-alignment, subcaption, variable

I have two external graphics that I want to add to my document side-by-side using the [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)-package at the same height. To get the height of the first file, I use `\settoheight`. In the subfigure this is used in, the value is correctly set. However, when I leave the subfigure, the value seems to be set to zero. Why is that? How can I pass the image height from the left to the right subfigure?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\figwidth}
\newlength{\figheight}
\newlength{\figdim}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.59\linewidth}
    % Length
    \setlength{\figwidth}{\linewidth}
    \setlength{\figheight}{5cm}
    \settoheight\figdim{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
    \setlength{\figheight}{\figdim}
    % Figure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\the\figdim, \the\figheight, left}%
    \label{fig:left}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.39\linewidth}
    % Length
    \setlength{\figwidth}{\linewidth}
    % Figure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\the\figdim, \the\figheight, right}%
    \label{fig:right}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Test}
  \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Related

- [Subcaption: Vertical alignment of two images of different vertical size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239128/44634)
- [Subcaption vertical alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204299/44634)

---

### Update

Following @Werner's approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\figwidth}
\newlength{\figheight}
\newlength{\figdim}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

  % Length
  \setlength{\figwidth}{0.59\linewidth}
  \setlength{\figheight}{5cm}
  \settoheight\figdim{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
  \setlength{\figheight}{\figdim}

  \begin{subfigure}{0.59\linewidth}
    % Figure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\the\figheight, left}%
    \label{fig2:left}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.39\linewidth}
    % Figure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\the\figheight, right}%
    \label{fig2:right}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Test}
  \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, one has to change the width factor (`x*\linewidth`) twice.

---

### Update 2

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\figwidth}
\newlength{\figheight}
\newlength{\figdim}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.59\linewidth}
    % Length
    \setlength{\figwidth}{0.7\linewidth}
    \setlength{\figheight}{5cm}
    \settoheight\figdim{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-16x9}}
    \global\setlength{\figwidth}{\figwidth}
    \global\setlength{\figheight}{\figdim}
    % Figure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-16x9}
    \caption{\the\figdim, \the\figheight, left}%
    \label{fig3:left}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.39\linewidth}
    % Length
    \setlength{\figwidth}{\linewidth}
    % Figure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-16x10}
    \caption{\the\figdim, \the\figheight, right}%
    \label{fig3:right}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Test}
  \label{fig3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of scoping - length changes are reverted if they're made within a group once you exit that group. Here's a minimal example showing this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\mylength}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\mylength}{100pt}
\the\mylength

\begingroup
\setlength{\mylength}{200pt}
\the\mylength
\endgroup

\the\mylength

\end{document}
```

Since you're capturing the image dimensions inside the `subfigure` environment, these lengths are lost as soon as you exit that environment.

The solution would be to gather than information within the `figure` environment, but outside the `subfigure` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\figwidth}
\newlength{\figheight}
\newlength{\figdim}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  % Length
  \setlength{\figwidth}{\linewidth}
  \setlength{\figheight}{5cm}
  \settoheight\figdim{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
  \setlength{\figheight}{\figdim}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.59\linewidth}
    % Figure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\the\figdim, \the\figheight, left}%
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.39\linewidth}
    % Length
    \setlength{\figwidth}{\linewidth}
    % Figure
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\figwidth,height=\figheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\the\figdim, \the\figheight, right}%
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see. This is problematic as the final dimensions of the left subfigure are dependent on `linewidth`, which changes in the `subfigure`. Thus I can only calculate the dimensions inside the subfigure. I could do that on the figure level, but I do have to include the factor of the subfigure width.

Comment: @krtek: If you must, you can use `\global\setlength{\figdim}{\figdim}` to achieve a `global` definition for `\figdim` that will be retained after the scope ends.

Comment: Thanks. Works great. I updated my questions with your solutions.