# Problem while using caption for rows of multiple figures in 2 columns and many rows

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I have a collection of 10*2 figures which are subfigures of a main figure. I have been able to place them in my Latex document. The result is like as follows:

```
a    b
c    d
.
.
.
Figure: 1 (Caption of Figure: 1).
```

But I want to put caption to each row as well and want my figure to look like:

```
a    b
{Caption of first row}
.
.
.
Figure: 1 {....}
```

How can I achieve the requested layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the entire sub-figure construction inside a `tabular` and then set by-pair captions as a regular `\multicolumn{2}{c}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\quad}c}
    \subcaptionbox{first}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}} &
    \subcaptionbox{second}{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}} \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is a mid-figure caption} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \subcaptionbox{third}{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}} &
    \subcaptionbox{fourth}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}} \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is another mid-figure caption} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \subcaptionbox{fifth}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}} &
    \subcaptionbox{sixth}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}} \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is a final mid-figure caption} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The spacing between the by-pair captions and their respective sub-figures can be adjusted.