# How to make Pie charts in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, subcaption

I’m trying to place two pie charts side by side but they overlap.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
%\adjustbox{trim=0 .01\height{} 0 .07\height{}, clip, width=.91\linewidth}
%  \includegraphics[page=1, width=\textwidth]{{sinus.gender}.pdf}
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      72/Female (13),
         28/Male (5)
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Sinus.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
%\adjustbox{trim=0 .02\height{} 0 .01\height{}, clip, width=.91\linewidth}
%  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, page=1]{{arr.gender}.pdf}

\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      47/Female (22),
        53/Male (25)
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

It would be really great to be able to `\input` or `\include` the tikz document to my code such that I do not need keep all codes in one document.

### Testing hhh's captions

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127227/subcaption-having-two-subfigures-captions-on-the-same-line
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \subcaptionbox{Sinus}%
     [.4\linewidth]{\firstPic}}
    \subcaptionbox{Arr.}%
    [.4\linewidth]{\secondPic}
\caption{Gender proportions in populations.}
\label{figure:gender}
\end{figure}
```

Output

[image]

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: There is a legend present in this image.  I don’t see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with Tikz, a remix of this [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart-color/) below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      72.2/Female (13),
        27.8/Male (5)
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Other possibilites exist such as `pgf-pie` package in Google Code by this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83194/2956):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Related**

- [Package for pie charts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5718/package-for-pie-charts)
- [How to draw Bar & Pie Chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135393/how-to-draw-bar-pie-chart)

---

**For having two pie charts side-by-side**

Firstly, use the macros. Then use the `showframe` package to see what kind of thing you are playing with.

[image]

and so we will scale the Tikz pictures

[image]

and then we will use `hfill` to add some extra space between the two pictures, success!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{showframe}


\newcommand{\firstPic}{
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      72/Female (13),
         28/Male (5)
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\secondPic}{
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      47/Female (22),
        53/Male (25)
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \firstPic
  \caption{Frist picture}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \secondPic
  \caption{Second picture}
  \end{subfigure}

\caption{MAIN caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

**Subcaptionbox aligning the subfigure subcaptions properly**

The first is with subfigures while the other is with subcaptionbox.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{showframe}


\newcommand{\firstPic}{
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      72/Female (13),
         28/Male (5)
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\secondPic}{
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      47/Female (22),
        53/Male (25)
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.7*\radius) {\percent\,\%};
        \node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
          at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \firstPic
  \caption{Frist subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \secondPic
  \caption{Second subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{MAIN caption for SUBFIGURES}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
        \subcaptionbox{First subcaptionbox}[0.45\textwidth]{\centering \firstPic}
          \hfill
        \subcaptionbox{Second subcaptionbox}[0.45\textwidth]{\centering \secondPic}
\caption{MAIN caption for SUBCAPTIONBOX}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

*P.s. I am thankful to Tor for helping me in the chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33698866#33698866).*

Comment: Can (a) and (b) be on the same line?

Comment: @Masi that is already answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127227/subcaption-having-two-subfigures-captions-on-the-same-line), you can solve it with `\subcaptionbox`.

Comment: Please, see the body for my attempt with `\subcaptionbox`.

Comment: @Masi see the newest update for the solution.