# Picture and Code Side by Side: Lstlisting not working inside \subcaptionbox

Tags: captions, listings, subcaption

I am trying to get source code and a picture side by side with two captions that are aligned with the upper part of the caption text as suggested in this thread: [Having two figures subcaption on the same line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127227/subcaption-having-two-subfigures-captions-on-the-same-line).

For the alignment someone suggested the `\subcaptionbox` environment. However, when trying to insert a lstlising into the \subcaptionbox environment in the following example I get multiple errors:

```latex
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Example of a parameterized type in Scala adopted from~\cite{2.13-types}}[.45\textwidth]{
  \begin{lstlisting}
class TreeMap[A <: Comparable[A], B] { … }
  \end{lstlisting}
}
\subcaptionbox{UML representation of parameterized type TreeMap}[.45\textwidth]{
  \includegraphics{parameterized-types.pdf}
}
\label{fig:scalaspecific:bounds}
\caption{Examplary UML representation of parameterized types}
\end{figure}
```

Produced Errors:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "80.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... }
! Argument of \lst@next has an extra }.<inserted text>\par }
...
```

I basically have two questions now.

First: Is there a fix to this, so that one can put lisitings inside `\subcaptionbox` environments?

Second: If there is no fix, is there another way to achieve same line caption alignment for a picture and code?

Comment: The `lstlisting` environment can't be the argument of a macro, instead of `\subcaptionbox`, you could use the `subfigure` environment.

Comment: but with `subfigure` the captions are aligned at the bottom, but I want them to be aligned at the top. Is it possible to achieve this with subfigure?

Comment: Put the code of your listing in a separate file. Then input the listing with `\lstinputlisting{<file>}` instead. This way you should be able to put the listing in the argument of `\subcaptionbox`. Also, you'll have to change `…` to `...` if you're using `pdflatex`.

Comment: `\lstinputlisting` seems to be the best solution, do you want to state an answer yourself, or should i provide a detailed answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the contents of your listing in an external file, you can put `\lstinputlisting` in the argument of `\subcaptionbox`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.lst}
class TreeMap[A <: Comparable[A], B] { ... }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,listings,graphicx}

\newsavebox{\listingsbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering

\subcaptionbox{Example of a parameterized type in Scala 
  adopted from~\cite{2.13-types}}[.45\linewidth]{%
      \lstinputlisting[breaklines]{\jobname.lst}%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{UML representation of parameterized type TreeMap}[.45\textwidth]{
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
}
\caption{Examplary UML representation of parameterized types\label{fig:scalaspecific:bounds}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Save the `lstlistings` environment in a box, which you can use inside `\subcaptionbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,listings,graphicx}

\newsavebox{\listingsbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering

\begin{lrbox}{\listingsbox}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
class TreeMap[A <: Comparable[A], B] { ... }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\subcaptionbox{Example of a parameterized type in Scala 
  adopted from~\cite{2.13-types}}{%
  \usebox{\listingsbox}%
}
\subcaptionbox{UML representation of parameterized type TreeMap}[.45\textwidth]{
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
}

\caption{Examplary UML representation of parameterized types}
\label{fig:scalaspecific:bounds}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\label` should go *after* `\caption`.

Comment: Well, technically it's best to put the `\label` *in* `\caption`.